# Message-digesting process in PKCS#7 (signature in PDF)

Tags: pdf, message, signature, digest, pkcs#7

The problem occurs in the verification of the signature in PDF file. It is said in the standard that:

> The result of the message digest calculation process depends on whether the signedAttrs field is present. When the field is absent, the result is just the message digest of the content as described above. When the field is present, however, the result is the message digest of the complete DER encoding of the SignedAttrs value contained in the signedAttrs field.

I parsed signature and got `signedAttrs`:

```
[0](4 elem)
   SEQUENCE(2 elem)
      OBJECT IDENTIFIER1.2.840.113549.1.9.3            // ContentType
      SET(1 elem)
        OBJECT IDENTIFIER1.2.840.113549.1.7.1
   SEQUENCE(2 elem)
      OBJECT IDENTIFIER1.2.840.113549.1.9.5            // SigningTime
      SET(1 elem)
        UTCTime2014-04-13 02:58:41 UTC
   SEQUENCE(2 elem)
      OBJECT IDENTIFIER1.2.840.113549.1.9.4            // MessageDigest
      SET(1 elem)
        OCTET STRING(20 byte) 194E0BA9C4B9A53D5E9E5B7B94D7DB42BEA4C28F
   SEQUENCE(2 elem)
      OBJECT IDENTIFIER1.2.840.113549.1.9.15
      SET(1 elem)
        SEQUENCE(8 elem)
          SEQUENCE(1 elem)
            OBJECT IDENTIFIER2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.42
          SEQUENCE(1 elem)
            OBJECT IDENTIFIER2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.22
          SEQUENCE(1 elem)
            OBJECT IDENTIFIER2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.2
          SEQUENCE(1 elem)
            OBJECT IDENTIFIER1.2.840.113549.3.7
          SEQUENCE(2 elem)
            OBJECT IDENTIFIER1.2.840.113549.3.2
            INTEGER128
          SEQUENCE(2 elem)
            OBJECT IDENTIFIER1.2.840.113549.3.2
            INTEGER64
          SEQUENCE(1 elem)
            OBJECT IDENTIFIER1.3.14.3.2.7
          SEQUENCE(2 elem)
            OBJECT IDENTIFIER1.2.840.113549.3.2
            INTEGER40
```

and DER encoding:

> A081D8301806092A864886F70D010903310B06092A864886F70D010701301C06092A864886F70D010905310F170D3134303431333032353834315A302306092A864886F70D01090431160414194E0BA9C4B9A53D5E9E5B7B94D7DB42BEA4C28F307906092A864886F70D01090F316C306A300B060960864801650304012A300B0609608648016503040116300B0609608648016503040102300A06082A864886F70D0307300E06082A864886F70D030202020080300D06082A864886F70D0302020140300706052B0E030207300D06082A864886F70D0302020128

I calculated its digest and compared to the result of decryption of encrypted digest. But it failed.

I should calculate digest on entire `signedAttrs` field or on some Attributes or on anything else?

**Edit**: 
This is [PDF file](https://www.mediafire.com/?uypwh54kmgg1g5d) I want to verify

Answer (score 6):

> I calculated its digest and compared to the result of decryption of encrypted digest. But it failed.

> I should calculate digest on entire signedAttrs field or on some Attributes or on anything else?

Have you considered that

> > the message digest of the complete DER encoding of the SignedAttrs value contained in the signedAttrs field

implies that **it is not the hash of *the SignedAttrs value* itself but *its complete DER encoding***? The difference is that the *SignedAttrs value* is implicitly 0-tagged:

```
signedAttrs [0] IMPLICIT SignedAttributes OPTIONAL
```

while *its complete DER encoding* is not. The standard even explicitly says this:

> > A separate encoding
> > of the signedAttrs field is performed for message digest calculation.
> > The IMPLICIT [0] tag in the signedAttrs is not used for the DER
> > encoding, rather an EXPLICIT SET OF tag is used.  That is, the DER
> > encoding of the EXPLICIT SET OF tag, rather than of the IMPLICIT [0]
> > tag, MUST be included in the message digest calculation along with
> > the length and content octets of the SignedAttributes value.

> > *(cf. section 5.4 of both [RFC 3852](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3852#section-5.4) and [RFC 5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-5.4))*

Thus, you have to replace the leading 0xA0 in your

> A081D8301806092A864886F70D010903310B06092A864886F70D010701301C06092A864886F70...

accordingly before calculating the digest.

Have you furthermore considered that *result of decryption of encrypted digest* (I hope you are talking about old-fashioned RSA signing, otherwise *decryption* is not helpful) is **not** the naked digest but instead the digest wrapped in a `DigestInfo` structure?

```
DigestInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
  digestAlgorithm DigestAlgorithmIdentifier,
  digest Digest }
```

**ADDITION**

Even after these clarifications there were some problems, cf. the comment

> I calculated digest on the complete DER encoding but it was different from digest after decrypted

Thus, here a bit of Java code using Bouncy Castle (maybe not used optimally, I'm more at home with a propriety crypto library) to calculate the hash of the signed attributes and extract the hash from the RSA signature:

```
    // The CMS container
    CMSSignedData cms = new CMSSignedData(bytes);

    // Calculating the digest of the signed attributes
    SignerInformation signerInformation = (SignerInformation) (cms.getSignerInfos().getSigners().iterator().next());
    byte[] derSignedAttributes = signerInformation.getEncodedSignedAttributes();
    MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    byte[] derSignedAttributesHash = sha1.digest(derSignedAttributes);
    
    // Retrieving the public key from the (single) certificate in the container
    X509CertificateHolder cert = (X509CertificateHolder) cms.getCertificates().getMatches(new Selector() {
        public boolean match(Object arg0) { return true; }
        public Object clone()             { return this; }
    }).iterator().next();
    X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(cert.getSubjectPublicKeyInfo().getEncoded());
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(publicKeySpec.getFormat());
    Key key = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

    // Decrypting the DigestInfo from the RSA signature
    Cipher asymmetricCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
    asymmetricCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] digestInfo = asymmetricCipher.doFinal(signerInformation.getSignature());
    DigestInfo digestInfoObject = new DigestInfo(ASN1Sequence.getInstance(digestInfo));

    System.out.println("Signed Attributes: " + toHex(derSignedAttributes));
    System.out.println("Signed Attributes Hash: " + toHex(derSignedAttributesHash));
    System.out.println("DigestInfo: " + toHex(digestInfo));
    System.out.println("DigestInfo Hash: " + toHex(digestInfoObject.getDigest()));
```

Applied to the signature in the provided PDF file signed_1047_ctsv.pdf the output is:

```
Signed Attributes: 31 81 D8 30 18 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 09 03 31 0B 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 07 01 30 1C 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 09 05 31 0F 17 0D 31 34 30 34 31 33 30 32 35 38 34 31 5A 30 23 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 09 04 31 16 04 14 19 4E 0B A9 C4 B9 A5 3D 5E 9E 5B 7B 94 D7 DB 42 BE A4 C2 8F 30 79 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 09 0F 31 6C 30 6A 30 0B 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 01 2A 30 0B 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 01 16 30 0B 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 01 02 30 0A 06 08 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 03 07 30 0E 06 08 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 03 02 02 02 00 80 30 0D 06 08 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 03 02 02 01 40 30 07 06 05 2B 0E 03 02 07 30 0D 06 08 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 03 02 02 01 28 
Signed Attributes Hash: 7A 2D D8 92 B0 F4 AC 5A 2C 93 03 6B 06 94 74 62 71 D0 06 17 
DigestInfo: 30 21 30 09 06 05 2B 0E 03 02 1A 05 00 04 14 7A 2D D8 92 B0 F4 AC 5A 2C 93 03 6B 06 94 74 62 71 D0 06 17 
DigestInfo Hash: 7A 2D D8 92 B0 F4 AC 5A 2C 93 03 6B 06 94 74 62 71 D0 06 17
```

As you see, the values *Signed Attributes Hash* and *DigestInfo Hash* are the same.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I dont understand what the complete DER encoding is? Can you give me an example?

Comment: The signed attributes are included in the PKCS#7 container with an `IMPLICIT [0]` tag (encoded as 0xA0). This means that this tag *replaces* the `SET OF` tag (encoded as 0x31) which would by definition of `SignedAttributes` be its outer, initial tag. For the *the complete DER encoding* you have to revert this, i.e. replace the leading 0xA0 again by 0x31.

Comment: So the complete DER encoding in this case is:
`3181d8301806092a864886f70d010903310b06092a864886f70d010701301c06092a864886f70d010905310f170d3134303431333032353834315a302306092a864886f70d01090431160414194e0ba9c4b9a53d5e9e5b7b94d7db42bea4c28f307906092a864886f70d01090f316c306a300b060960864801650304012a300b0609608648016503040116300b0609608648016503040102300a06082a864886f70d0307300e06082a864886f70d030202020080300d06082a864886f70d0302020140300706052b0e030207300d06082a864886f70d0302020128`

And I will calculate digest on it?

Comment: I calculated digest on the _complete DER encoding_ but it was different from digest after decrypted (I mean `Digest`, not `DigestInfo`)

Comment: Please share the file in question for analysis.

Comment: This is signed PDF file. [https://www.mediafire.com/?uypwh54kmgg1g5d](https://www.mediafire.com/?uypwh54kmgg1g5d)

Comment: Could you verify it successfully? Help me please. It's very important to me

Comment: *Could you verify it successfully* - Yes I could, cf the addition to my answer.

Comment: Could you show me value of `Signed Attributes` which was hashed, NOT in hexadecimal. This value is in hex or decimal or binary?

Comment: *Could you show me value of Signed Attributes which was hashed, NOT in hexadecimal* - If not in hexadecimal, how then? ASN.1 style description?

Comment: Because I hashed value in hexadecimal and it was different. I think the value, which was hashed, must be in binary or another.
I see in your java code, `System.out.println("Signed Attributes: " + toHex(derSignedAttributes))`, you used function toHex() to print value in hexadecimal. Could you try to print this value without using toHex()?

Comment: *Because I hashed value in hexadecimal* - that is wrong of course. I assumed all the time we were using hexadecimal writing because the actual data is binary. *Could you try to print this value without using toHex()?* - Well, the output would be hard to read and (if pasted here) incompletely transmitted because there are multiple bytes in the control character range and some higher bytes probably also without character representation.

Comment: Yeah, I did it. It must be in binary. Thank you so so much! 
You are my hero!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I'm voting this up because it's helpful, unfortunately it didn't actually work for me.  It actually threw an exception when I specified the BC provider, but when I took that out it ran, but I still got different values when comparing the signed attributes and the digest.

Comment: @Amber please make that a question in its own right. In particular *an exception when* you *specified the BC provider* should not happen.